# Retrieve a value of xml node (according to a specific attribute) using java

Tags: java, xml

I have this XML file:

```
<DOC id="3046302">
<Tag id="1923">
    <description>COMPANY_NAME</description>
    <value>My Demo</value>
</Tag>

<Tag id="1924">
    <description>RECIPIENT_FIRST_NAME</description>
    <value>Clientfpd</value>
</Tag>

<Tag id="1925">
    <description>RECIPIENT_SURNAME</description>
    <value>Sanity</value>
</Tag>
```

I need to write a JAVA program which returns the value "My Demo" if the Tag id is "1923", or returns the value "Clientfpd" if the tag id is "1924", etc...

Explanation: the Tag id should be the parameter for the JAVA method (for example: "1923"), and the method should read the xml and returns the value of `<value>` tag.
I have tried to write this program but I didn't succeed with that at all (I'm new to JAVA).
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please explain exactly where you are stuck, and add the code you have so far to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by constructing an XPath with id value taken from parameter.

Example:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class XPathDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String tagValueParam = "1923";
        String docString = "<DOC id=\"3046302\">\n" //
                + "<Tag id=\"1923\">\n" //
                + "    <description>COMPANY_NAME</description>\n" //
                + "    <value>My Demo</value>\n"//
                + "</Tag>\n"//
                + "\n"//
                + "<Tag id=\"1924\">\n"//
                + "    <description>RECIPIENT_FIRST_NAME</description>\n"//
                + "    <value>Clientfpd</value>\n"//
                + "</Tag>\n"//
                + "\n"//
                + "<Tag id=\"1925\">\n"//
                + "    <description>RECIPIENT_SURNAME</description>\n"//
                + "    <value>Sanity</value>\n"//
                + "</Tag>\n"//
                + "</DOC>";
        Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(docString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));

        Object result = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("/DOC/Tag[@id='" + tagValueParam + "']/value")
                .evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        if (result != null && result instanceof Element) {
            System.out.println(((Element) result).getTextContent());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! a question - how can I write this program with a variable which contains the path to the XML doc? (in your program, you copied the xml into docString variable..but I need a variable which contains the path to the XML). Thanks!

Comment: String docPath = "/Users/mvmn/tmp/test.xml";
  Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(new File(docPath))));